# No response from server wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have published an api, it is working perfectly. Sometimes api's returning no content from server as response, after restarting it is working properly.
Please help to resolve this issue.

I have observed different error logs.

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-30 20:57:38,264] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller} -   {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-30 21:10:57,174] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor} -   {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor}


TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-30 17:34:37,379] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.client.state.AMQStateManager} -  Notifying Waiters([org.wso2.andes.client.state.StateWaiter@79a55969]) for error:not allowed {org.wso2.andes.client.state.AMQStateManager}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-30 17:34:37,380] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler} -  AMQP timed out when attempting to close the connection  {org.wso2.andes.client.protocol.AMQProtocolHandler}
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-30 17:34:37,385] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection} -  Throwable Received but no listener set: org.wso2.andes.AMQException: AMQP timed out when attempting to close the connection  {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection}
```

Comment: Please, show  in, out and fault sequences of your API. Maybe your fault seq supresses error processing and just returns an empty response?